# Fitting a plane to points in three ways

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, analytic-geometry, regression

I have a collection of points $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ in 3D space, and I want to fit a plane to these points. Clearly this is a minimization problem -- I want to minimize some "total measure" of the distance from the points to my plane.

Suppose $d_i$ is the distance from the point $P_i$ to my plane. I can think of (at least) three quantities that I could try to minimize:
$$
\text{Minimize} \quad D_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i 
\quad \text{ giving me a plane} \;\pi_1
$$
$$
\text{Minimize} \quad D_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2
\quad \text{ giving me a plane} \;\pi_2$$
$$
\text{Minimize} \quad D_3 = \max_{1\le i \le n} d_i
\quad \text{ giving me a plane} \;\pi_3$$
**My question: Are there any relationships between $D_1, D_2, D_3$ or between their associated planes $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$?**

The reason I ask is that $\pi_3$ is what I really care about, but $D_2$ looks like it would be much easier to minimize. I’m wondering whether finding $\pi_2$ will help me find $\pi_3$.

Comment: The usual process for minimizing $D_2$ is called “principal component analysis”. I suspect that minimizing $D_1$ amounts to a linear programming problem.

Comment: There are some obvious inequalities we could come up with. For example, $D_3^2 \leq D_2 \leq n D_3^2$.

Comment: Yeah, #2 is just standard least-squares fitting, so it boils down to SVD or finding eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix. Well understood, even by me. What I’d like to know is whether this helps with #3.

Comment: Obviously, $\pi_2$ leads to an upper bound to the minimum that you get in problem $\#3$. I don't know of any other way to use an answer to $\#2$ to help with an answer to $\#3$.

Comment: Could you joint to your question at least one representative example of your data.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Typical data would be a set of dozens or hundreds of points that are almost planar, covering an area of around 100 cm^2. By “almost” I mean that the points deviate from some (unknown) plane by around 0.1 mm or so. The points might come from a scanner, for example.

Comment: @bubba. To make the calculus aesily reproducible by any one there is no need for a big data. A limited number of points is sufficient. That's all one need to write a concret and not ambiguous answer.

Comment: Wouldn't #3 be the limit of a p-norm version of #2 (p instead of 2), p goes to infinity (or in practicality a number like 10) and then you take the pth root after optimizing?

Comment: If $N$ is a unit normal of $\pi_3$, then $2D_3=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max}N\cdot P_i-\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\min}N\cdot P_i$, so you have a simple continuous function to optimize over a half sphere. If $\pi_3$ contain the average of two points with maximal distance from $\pi_3$, then you can likely tilt $\pi_3$ a bit through their average without increasing $D_3$, so $D_3(N)$ is likely constant in a neighborhood of an optimum.

Comment: On stats.stackexchange.com there may be some people who have spent some years thinking through this question.